# Updating Momentjs FromNow() in a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I'm having this div element that shows the time past since it got created. However it doesn't get updated and always remains on **few seconds ago**. It looks like this

```
var newMsg= "<div id="chat-time">'+ moment().fromNow()+'</div>";
 $("#chat-list").html( newMsg);
```

How can I update this text. I know I can do it with sentInterval but I can't figure out how to do it properly.It just prints out seconds! I'm using this for a chatroom. So each message will have a timestamp in the formatof momentjs.fromNow(). 
Does setting timer for all these message create a problem? I'd appreciate a hint.

**EDIT**:I'm using this code as mentioned in below but it's not showing anything:

```
<div id="chat-time"></div>

var messageTimeStamp = new Date();
setInterval(function(){
    var time = moment(messageTimeStamp).fromNow();

    $("#chat-time").html(time);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: that code makes no sense , please show full context of it's use. `setInterval()` returns a unique identifier for each use  so it can be canceled. Your code will never return the `moment()` value to that string

Comment: @charlietfl so how can I update that text every second?

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Let me know if my answer doesn't work for you.  I provided a demo, as well.

Comment: @HiradRoshandel You would need to put the HTML in the HTML file and the JavaScript in the JS file or inside a `<script></script>` tag.  Look at the demo I provided to see it working:http://plnkr.co/edit/QuaMV6x1vNB0kYPaU6i1?p=preview

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I think the reason for now working is that chat-time does not exist at that moment because I;'m creating the content at that time

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Are you storing the messages on a server/database or is this chatroom single-browser-only?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I'm using socket.io for this

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Okay I've updated my answer again.  Please review and adapt it to your code. I may not have done everything the same you did.  Also I'm about to make a plunker to make sure I don't have any typos.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Ill try it and let you know

Comment: @HiradRoshandel: I got the plunker working and updated my answer.  Here it is:  http://plnkr.co/edit/QuaMV6x1vNB0kYPaU6i1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

Given that you're using socket.io, you'd do something like this (demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QuaMV6x1vNB0kYPaU6i1?p=preview):

```
  // The messages the user can currently see.
  var messages = [];

  // You have something like this in your code, presumably.
  socket.on('new message', function(data) {
    addChatMessage(data);
  });

  function addChatMessage(data) {
    // First add the message to the dome, with a unique id for the timestamp text.
    var messageElementId = 'chat-message-' + data.messageId;
    $("#chat-list").prepend($("<div>" + data.message + "<i> (sent: <span id='" + messageElementId + "'>just now</span>)</i></div>"));

    // When you no longer display that message in the DOM it from clear this array.  I'd render the DOM based on this list if I were you.
    messages.push({
      messageElementId: messageElementId,
      timestamp: data.timestamp
    });
  }

  // By updating all the messages at once you don't have memory leaks.
  setInterval(function() {
    messages.forEach(function(message) {
      var time = moment(message.timestamp).fromNow();
      $("#" + message.messageElementId).text(time);
    });
  }, 1000);
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

Given this is your code:

```
var newMsg= "<div id="chat-time">'+ moment().fromNow()+'</div>";
$("#chat-list").html(newMsg);
```

You would do this, instead:

```
var messageTimeStamp = new Date(); // You need to grab this from somewhere.

setInterval(function(){
  var time = moment(messageTimeStamp).fromNow();        
  $("#chat-list").html(time);
}, 1000);
```

---

You need to use `moment(TIMESTAMP_OF_MESSAGE)` not `moment()` and do something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("body").append($('<div id="chat-time"></div>'));

  var messageTimeStamp = new Date();
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    var time = moment(messageTimeStamp).fromNow();

    $("#chat-time").html('moment().from(messageTimeStamp): ' + time + '; setInterval calls made ' + i++);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Here's a demo.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QuaMV6x1vNB0kYPaU6i1?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't work. it shows no result :-/ I update my question with your code

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need the element in the dom and the `setInterval` running without being included in any string concatenation

HTML

```
<div id="chat-time"></div>
```

JS

```
var $chatTime = $('#chat-time').text(moment().fromNow());
setInterval(function(){ 
   var time = moment().fromNow();
    $chatTime.txt( time );
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any problem using `setInterval ()`. AngularJS wrapper setInterval  on $interval service module . Check out these urls: [interval Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and [Wrapper SetInterval](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/refresh-div-angularjs-interval/)

Comment: I'm not using angular

Comment: I understand. But i just want to show you  that is not ugly use setInterval. Words Like Jared code works for me like a charm.

Comment: I understand but coding everything all over again in agular is not the answer to this question. thanks though. btw that downvote was not mine.

Comment: Ok. Sorry by the way.